# python - adding a argument to execution script

Tags: python

consider I am having a following code in my bin as follows(filename: emp_dsb):

```
import sys

from employee_detail_collector.EmpCollector import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

In my command line I will execute the **"emp_dsb"**, so that above code will execute the main function from "employee_detail_collector.EmpCollector"

Code in (employee_detail_collector.EmpCollector) main():

```
def main():
    try:
        path = const.CONFIG_FILE
        empdsb = EmpDashboard(path)
    except SONKPIExceptions as e:
        logger.error(e.message)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)
```

Now I need to add some argument here for emp_dsb, that is like **"emp_dsb create_emp**" should invoke a new set of functionalities for creating a employee, which is also needs to be added in same main()

someone look and let me know your ideas, If not clear let me know so that i will try to make it more clear.

Comment: google for `python argh`

Comment: hint: use `sys.argv`

Answer (score 1):

the standard way to use command line arguments is to do this:

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(sys.argv)
```

read up on the doc of [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

then there are fancier ways like the built-in [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) and the 3rd party [`docopt`](http://docopt.org/) or [`click`](http://click.pocoo.org/).

Comment: This would be a better answer with @Shobeir's answer added. Though still the best answer yet.

Comment: @EmettSpeer: i agree, a little more example code might be nice. but as i mentioned 4 libraries i did not want to present 4 examples or lead the choice of a tool in a certain direction by giving an example for one tool only... besides: the documentation is pretty good on each of those.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use 'argparse' module. 
[Here is the link to a dead simple code sample](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/argparse.html#introducing-positional-arguments).

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("echo")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.echo)
```